# Compile error when define and use class variable in Qt QStyledItemDelegate

Tags: c++, qt, delegates

I define a `MsgNameIdDelegate` class that inherits from `QStyledItemDelegate`:

**Header file:**

```
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class MsgNameIdDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MsgNameIdDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);

protected:
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;

private:
    int I;
};

#endif // MsgNameIdDelegate_H
```

**Source file:**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPainter>

MsgNameIdDelegate::MsgNameIdDelegate(QObject *parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

QSize MsgNameIdDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index ) const
{
    qDebug()<<I;
}

void MsgNameIdDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    I = 10;
    QApplication::style()->drawItemText(painter, option.rect, Qt::AlignHCenter|Qt::AlignVCenter| Qt::TextLongestVariant, option.palette, true, "Example");
}
```

As you can see, I define a class variable named by `I`. But, when I compile my code, I get the following compile error:

```
msgnameiddelegate.cpp:85:7: error: cannot assign to non-static data member within const member function 'paint'
msgnameiddelegate.cpp:77:25: note: member function 'MsgNameIdDelegate::paint' is declared const here
```

Also, when I define variable `I` as static variable, I get the following compile error:

```
in function `MsgNameIdDelegate::sizeHint(QStyleOptionViewItem const&, QModelIndex const&) const':
msgnameiddelegate.cpp:(.text+0x23b): undefined reference to `MsgNameIdDelegate::I'
```

**Note:**  I use Qt 5.15.2 in Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `const` qualifier in the *declaration* of the `paint` function of your `MsgNameIdDelegate` class tells the compiler that that function **does not modify** the class object on which it is called. However, in the *definition* of that function, you ***do*** (try to) modify the object, in the `I = 10;` statement.

You need to either: (a) remove the `const` qualifier; or (b) declare the `I` member as `static` (as you have tried) *and then provide a definition of that variable* (in your source file), with a line like this:

```cpp
int MsgNameIdDelegate::I{0};
```

However, bear in mind that using the `static` option will mean that there is only one instance of that `I` variable, shared by all objects of the class.

Comment: Thx, but in solution (a), I could not remove `const` from function definition, because  `QStyledItemDelegate` is the internal Qt class. For solution (b), as you suggest correctly, I try to define a variable for each object and do not share between all objects, so static variable does not useful.

Comment: @AbolfazlDiyanat I'm not sure why your class being derived from an internal Qt class prevents you from removing the `const` qualifier. The `MsgNameIdDelegate` class is *yours* so can you can do what you like with it (within reasonable limits). Unless you are overriding a `virtual` base member function?

Comment: I inherit from `QStyledItemDelegate`. This class is an implementation of abstract class `QStyledItemDelegate`. Both of them are Qt internal class. This is the definition of `paint` function in `QStyledItemDelegate` class :  `virtual void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const = 0;`.

Comment: @AbolfazlDiyanat OK, fair point. Then I would suggest that, if the Qt implementation says that the `paint` function shouldn't modify its class, then you should abide by that 'rule' and rethink your override/implementation.